# GTA V Online Heists Replay effect on Heist Challenges

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Does replaying a Heist in online mode (especially the first heist) affect the [Heist Challenges](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Heist_Challenges) ? For example, will playing the first heist twice (same 2 crew members that will later make part of the 4) null and void the rest of the challenges?

Backstory: We're a crew of 3 who needs a 4th for the heists, we have guy lined up, but it's a while until he can play, so we want to rock out with the first heist mission for a while (if we can)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 10 million GTA$ challenge you need to finish all 5 heists on hard with the same crew in a row, you can always start fresh from the Fleeca heists once you have completed all heists.